# I am getting a resource not found error when building a project using the xamarin IDE

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

When the project is built the following output file in abc_screen_toolbar.xml contains the error

```
<android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer
            android:id="@+id/action_bar_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            style="?attr/actionBarStyle"
            android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="true"
            android:gravity="top">
```

also currently my project does not use any touch screen features.

**Screenshot of the output file :** 
[image: outputfile]

Answer (score 0):

**Solution :** Set your target API level to 21 or higher

---

Refer :

- https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=32522

Comment: Thanks for your answer and edits Vaikesh, where on the Xamarin Studio can I set the target API Level? (I am trying to look for it at the moment)

Comment: Thanks Vaikesh found the setting for changing the Target API, still struggling to get the right results on the emulator, this may be due to hard disk memory problems on this computer but that's another issue.